Where should I take the measurement from to find the correct attenuation level of a resistive pi attenuator?
I am currently designing a resistive attenuator for an RF project I'm working on. I wanted to have several resistance combinations to obtain various attenuation levels (1-8 dBs). When I calculate the resistance values by hand with the equations given here and/or use the Le Leivre tool, I get similar results. However, when I simulate the circuit on LTspice, I get very different levels of attenuation.
For example, the figure below shows circuits with the values I obtained from Le Leivre (top) and the values that I obtained by trial and error (bottom), later verified from Le Leivre. They are both matched for 50 Ohms of impedance and the values that I came up with result in a 1.002 dB attenuation according to Le Leivre.

Figure 1: Pi Attenuators with Values Obtained (Top) and Calculated (Bottom)
My problem is that when I measure the attenuation using AC analysis, the results show that the attenuation of the circuit with the Le Leivre values is exactly 1 dB while the attenuation of the circuit that I designed is around 1.15 dB.
My guess is that I am not measuring from the correct node. I am currently measuring from the nodes that connect R4 - R2_LL - R1_LL and the over the 50-Ohm load resistor (Same nodes with different names for my circuit as well). However changing the measurement nodes did not work. I seem to get the exact attenuation level when I use the Le Leivre values for any level of attenuation but a completely different attenuation when I use my own values...
Any help on how I can correctly measure the attenuation level with any resistor value I use is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The 50ohm->50ohm divider gives you an additional 6.02dB attenuation.  So when you measure at the 50ohm load resistor the total attenuation should be 1dB+6.02dB=7.02dB.  To compensate for the additional 6.02dB attenuation, you can change your voltage source to AC 2.

Wow, that solved it. Kinda feel embarrassed.. I was trying to compensate for that with a division at the traces section. I tried this for other values as well and it works just fine. Would you mind telling me how you came to this conclusion? Should I derive an AC amplitude for simulations where my output measurement is the node of a voltage divider?

No need to fell embarrassed.  An equal voltage divider results in multiplying by 0.5.  So multiplying the input signal by 2 (the reciprocal of 0.5) cancels that out.  Sure, you could do this for alternate divider ratios.  An alternative way would be to edit what you plot in the waveform viewer.  For example, instead of V(n003) you can do 2*V(n003).  Yet another way is to buffer what you want to measure into an "E-source" (symbol name is e) with a gain value that's the reciprocal of the divider attenuation.  All these methods do the same thing...they just adjust the measurement.

I see, well thank you for the explanation. I'll be sure to keep an eye out for these instances in the future.
